# PHP page to get results of MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I haven't a clue on how to write PHP but one of the sites I oversee uses it. I'd like to have a pie chart that automatically updates based on current data. I know how to write the HTML that will draw the chart but don't know how to get my MySQL statement to interact with the data. Here's the piece of code I want to run:

```
SELECT
pc.shortname Name,
Count(qa.factor) Count

FROM
stable_host pc,
stable_area pq,
stable_area_front qa

WHERE
pc.id = pq.host
AND pq.id = qa.area
AND ((pq.name='Signal1') OR (pq.name='Signal5'))

GROUP BY pc.shortname

ORDER BY pc.shortname
```

When I run this script, it gives me the following output:

```
Category1   62
Category2   53
Category3   35
Category4   38
```

My question is this: How do I get the output so it just shows the numbers, comma delimited? (Example: "62,53,35,38")

Answer (score 2):

```
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(count(qa.factor) SEPARATOR ',') count
```

I believe this is what you're asking.

Comment: I get error `#1111, Invalid Use of group function` when I use this code. If I leave the 'count' part of it out, it doesn't give me the error -- but it also doesn't give me what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
<?php 
$dsn = '';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$query = "Paste your query here";

try {
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
  $pdo->prepare($query);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Could not connect to the database\n");
}
    $results = $pdo->fetchAll();
if(count($results) > 0) {
    $array = array(); 
    foreach($queryResult as $row) {
      $array[] = $row['Count'];
    }
    $commaDelimitedString = implode(',',$array);
} // No need for end PHP tag, they cause problems.
```

This:
 - connects to database (or tries to)
 - runs your query
 - makes an empty array
 - loops over your results
 - takes the "Count" column and adds it to the end of the array
 - compresses the array into a comma-delimited string.

Look here (http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2004/may/first-steps-with-pdo/ and http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-pdo-bound-placeholders/) for some guidance on the usage of PDO and what you'll need to connect to the database (don't post those details, obviously)

It may look daunting, but just go one step at a time. If you have more questions just ask.

Comment: I don't understand. Where does my SQL statement fit in to this? Where would my table names/field names go? Would this be the whole PHP code? I see other pages that start with `<?` and end with `?>`. Would your statement above just go between those?

Comment: I'll expand (sorry thought you already had some of this written up)

Comment: I looked at the examples you gave for PDO but can't get past the database. Your example above just keeps saying `Can't connect to the database` no matter what I do. My DSN looks like this: `'mysql:host=MyHost;dbname=MyDBName';`  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That looks perfect to me.. perhaps try other way around, see the first example here http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: Still not working. Either I completely break it or it can't connect to the database. I am stumped, which is not hard to do in this situation.